# Possible to make API GET calls directly with the browser?

Tags: rest-api, api, httprequest, session-id

Im following this documentation about report filters via URL:
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=reports_filter_url.htm&type=5

But treat this only as use case example. I want to clarify this in general terms.

In the link above, it says:

> To see the order of filters in your report, refer to their order in
>   the report builder. Alternatively, make a GET call to
>   /services/data/v39.0/analytics/reports//describe and note
>   their order in the JSON response.

Now I have tried to make the GET request directly via browser by pasting the given URL above and replacing the id placeholder with a valid report Id.

```
https://MYDOMAIN.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v39.0/analytics/reports/MY-VALID-ID/describe/
```

I only get

```
<Errors>
    <Error>
        <errorCode>INVALID_SESSION_ID</errorCode>
        <message>Session expired or invalid</message>
    </Error>
</Errors>
```

I have a good idea on how to make a "real" REST-call, but I would be interested if there might be some quick&dirty approach to get it via the browser?

Comment: I don't think it is possible directly from the browser without authentication. But, you can try workbench REST Explorer. It will give you the response.

Comment: You can also use Postaman within Google.

Answer (score 2):

The endpoint you are referencing is part of the [Reports and Dashboards REST API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_analytics.meta/api_analytics/sforce_analytics_rest_api_get_reportmetadata.htm). You need to include an authentication token as a Header in your GET request. Details on how to authenticate via OAuth 2.0 here: [User Agent OAuth flow](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_understanding_user_agent_oauth_flow.htm).

As the commenters mentioned, the two most user friendly ways to access this endpoint is via:

- [Workbench](https://workbench.developerforce.com/login.php) > Utilities > REST Explorer
- [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/apps)